# Azure AD B2C Multi steps custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

We are using Azure AD B2C custom policies for our sign up process and we have multiple steps (multiple screens) before actually creating the user in Azure AD B2C using the AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail technical profile.

Let's say we have 3 steps defined by the following 3 technical profiles:

First step:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail-FirstStep">
      <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
        <Item Key="EnforceEmailVerification">True</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="title" Required="true"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" Required="true"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" Required="true"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <!-- no user created at this point -->
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

Second step :

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail-SecondStep">
      <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
        <Item Key="EnforceEmailVerification">True</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <!-- no user created at this point -->
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

Third step :

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail-ThirdStep">
      <DisplayName>Email Signup</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.riskwarningtermsconditions</Item>
        <Item Key="EnforceEmailVerification">False</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />

        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="agreeTermsConditions" Required="true"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="agreeRiskWarning" Required="true"/>
      </OutputClaims>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

And of course, we have a user journey using these 3 steps in sequence ending by the issuing of the token.

If we use the user journey as is, at the end of it, the user is indeed created but is blocked for sign in on Azure portal.[image]

If we change the order of the collected claims and we now collect the password claim during the last step, then the user is correctly created and not blocked for sign in. So it seems that password is a special claim...

From a UX perspective, we want the user to enter his password at step 2. What could we missing in our configuration ? (tech profile or user journey).

My AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail looks like that :

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail">
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
        <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">true</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
      <InputClaimsTransformations>
        <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateDisplayNameFromFirstNameAndLastName" />
      </InputClaimsTransformations>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true" />
      </InputClaims>
      <PersistedClaims>
        <!-- Required claims -->
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" PartnerClaimType="password"/>
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" DefaultValue="unknown" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="passwordPolicies" DefaultValue="DisablePasswordExpiration" />

        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />

        <!-- Optional claims. -->
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
      </PersistedClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" PartnerClaimType="newClaimsPrincipalCreated" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If an account is created without a password, then it is disabled for sign-in.

i.e. The **accountEnabled** property for the **User** object is set to `false`.

I believe this account is being created without a password because a password claim (e.g. the **newPassword** claim) can't be passed from one step (i.e. your second step) to another one (i.e. your third step).

i.e. A password claim is "scoped" to a given step.

This means the orchestration step that collects the password claim from the end user must be the same step that writes it to the **User** object.

Comment: Thx a lot Chris!!

Comment: hmm I tried it and still it does not work... The user is still blocked... Any suggestion ?

Comment: I have added my AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail technical profile if it helps

Comment: Hi @ben. I've updated the above answer with an alternative response that describes how I envisage this is happening. i.e. That a password claim can't be passed from one step to another one.

Comment: Hmm.. That&#39;s not good... Because even if we create the ad b2c user at step 2 then if the user cancels the sign up process at a later stage, we have a ghost user on the directory... And this brings all sort of concerns (having a job to clear the users but we will run into scenarios where a user cancels a sign up by mistake and wants to try again straight away, etc...)

Comment: @ben did you come to a solution to this?

Comment: @Chrift unfortunately no !

Comment: I've cleaned the above answer up to highlight that passing a password claim from one step to another one is a current limitation of the Azure AD B2C engine.

Comment: @ChrisPadgett what are the security implication of copying the `newPassword` claim to a different claim that can be passed to different steps?