# Can you pass password claims between steps in Azure AD B2C Custom Policies?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Can you pass password claims between steps in Azure AD B2C Custom Policies?

My symptom is that after signing up using a multiple page custom policy, a user cannot sign in until they reset their password.

I am asking this as I spent many hours debugging a problem that it turns out could not be fixed. I found the answer under another question ([Azure AD B2C Multi steps custom policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49206782/azure-ad-b2c-multi-steps-custom-policy)) that was differently worded but had similar symptoms.

I am posting here in the hope it is more easily found and helpful to others. Apologies if you think this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

In short, no. See [Azure AD B2C Multi steps custom policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49206782/azure-ad-b2c-multi-steps-custom-policy).

> A password claim is "scoped" to a given step. This means the orchestration step that collects the password claim from the end user must be the same step that writes it to the User object.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for the same and have found a way to do multi step sign up. I tried several methods, including a outputclaimstransformation to store the password in another claim, but that did not work out. Because I already needed to do some input validation against an API I found a way to also copy the password to a new claim (plaintextPassword) that is not scoped to one orchestration step. This claim can be used in a later step to create the user account with the password provided by the plaintextPassword claim.

Create a self asserted technical profile that has an inputclaim (the password) and a validation technical profile. In the validation technical profile you can copy the password to a claim of type string with an inputclaimstransformation. Then add the new claim as outputclaim to the validation profile and to the technical profile. See code below for an example:

```
  <ClaimType Id="plaintextPassword">
    <DisplayName>password</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
  </ClaimType>

  <ClaimType Id="password">
    <DisplayName>Your password</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <UserHelpText>Your password</UserHelpText>
    <UserInputType>Password</UserInputType>
  </ClaimType>

  <ClaimsTransformation Id="CopyPassword" TransformationMethod="FormatStringClaim">
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
    </InputClaims>
    <InputParameters>
      <InputParameter Id="stringFormat" DataType="string" Value="{0}" />
    </InputParameters>
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="plaintextPassword" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
    </OutputClaims>
  </ClaimsTransformation>

  <TechnicalProfile Id="SignUp-PasswordValidation">
    <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <Metadata>
      <Item Key="ServiceUrl">url</Item>
      <Item Key="AuthenticationType">ClientCertificate</Item>
      <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <CryptographicKeys>
      <Key Id="ClientCertificate" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_ClientCertificate" />
    </CryptographicKeys>
    <InputClaimsTransformations>
      <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CopyPassword" />
    </InputClaimsTransformations>
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="claim_to_validate" PartnerClaimType="claim_to_validate" />
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="plaintextPassword" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
  </TechnicalProfile>

  <TechnicalProfile Id="SignUp">
    <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
    <Metadata>
      <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
      <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignup</Item>
      <Item Key="setting.retryLimit">3</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <CryptographicKeys>
      <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
    </CryptographicKeys>
    <InputClaims>
      <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" Required="true" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="claim_to_validate" Required="true" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
      <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="plaintextPassword" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="SignUp-Validation" />
    </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
  </TechnicalProfile>
```

In the technical profile where you create the user in AAD add this line:

```
  <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="plaintextPassword" PartnerClaimType="password"/>
```

Comment: Do you know the security implications of doing this?

Comment: The implication is that the plaintext password becomes available in other steps of your user journey. I don't see any direct security implications, except that you have to be careful where you use the plaintext password (e.g. not storing it in AD B2C as an attribute or sending it as a claim to a relying party). But since you have access to the plaintext password in the step where it is entered, you could have already sent it to an API in the same step. In other words, it's up to the programmer to handle this responsibly, but from Azure AD B2C itself I don't see any additional risks.

Comment: Makes sense, but I still feel there's a good reason why the newPassword claim is not persisted by default. I wish I knew why. While this approach works I'm still hesitant to use it as I have security concerns.

Comment: I think this a good explanation and i agree with it. But I'd like to stress the importance of being very careful with this approach. For example, if you enable application insights in your custom policy and persist the password claim across steps, it will be stored as plaintext in application insights.

Comment: @badsyntax, that's a good point, I was wondering if there's a way to disable application insights for this password claim only. I have a similar scenario where I need to pass password between steps

Answer (score 1):

I removed the validation that called the technical profile that is written in AAD and changed it to a validation that calls another technical profile.

This will copy the password through a ClaimsTransformation that will save our password in another InputClaim to be visible in any other step of our flow.

```html
<TechnicalProfile Id="SignUp-PasswordValidation">
 <Metadata>
      <Item Key="ServiceUrl">url</Item>
      <Item Key="AuthenticationType">ClientCertificate</Item>
      <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
 </Metadata>

What is the url you used?

<CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
</CryptographicKeys>

What was you application to create the Secret?
```

Comment: Could you add a description, even if its short. Explaining how this solves the question and how / where this code should be added.

Comment: Hello, I was able to solve the problem.

When we have to add the user information (LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail)
I removed the validation that called the technical profile that is written in AAD, I changed it to a validation that calls another technical profile.
This will copy our password through a ClaimsTransformation that will save our password in another InputClaim to be visible in any other step of our flow.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem. When we have to add the user information (LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail) I removed the validation that called the technical profile that is written in AAD, I changed it to a validation that calls another technical profile. This will copy our password through a ClaimsTransformation that will save our password in another InputClaim to be visible in any other step of our flow.

```html
<ClaimType Id="plaintextPassword">
    <DisplayName>password</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
</ClaimType>

<ClaimType Id="passwordTransformation">
    <DisplayName>requestSocialRestSecondCall</DisplayName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
</ClaimType>

<ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
    <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="TransformationPassword" />
</ValidationTechnicalProfiles>


<ClaimsProvider> <!-- Copy Password-->
    <DisplayName>Copy Password</DisplayName>
    <TechnicalProfiles> 

        <TechnicalProfile Id="TransformationPassword">
            <DisplayName>Copy Pass</DisplayName>
            <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
            <InputClaims>
                <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="passwordTransformation" />
            </InputClaims>
            <OutputClaims>
                <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="passwordTransformation" />
            </OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaimsTransformations>
                <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="Generate_TranformationPassword" />
            </OutputClaimsTransformations>
        </TechnicalProfile>

    </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>



 <ClaimsTransformation Id="Generate_TranformationPassword" TransformationMethod="CopyClaim">
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" TransformationClaimType="inputClaim" />
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="plaintextPassword" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
    </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

Comment: Are there any security implications by doing this?