# Get current password in Azure B2C XML Custom Policy

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I need to retieve both the current password and the new password the user has set in a XML custom policy and pass that to an API endpoint.

Is this possible? I've tried to get the password using the Read operation of AAD-Common. I created a technical profile which successfully retrieves a custom attribute extension_RegisteredUserId, but if I add an output claim for the password I get the error:

New-AzureADMSTrustFrameworkPolicy : Error occurred while executing NewTrustFrameworkPolicy
Code: AADB2C
Message: Validation failed: 1 validation error(s) found in policy "B2C_1A_PASSWORDRESET" of tenant "rhsb2cdev.onmicrosoft.com".Output Claim 'password'
is not supported in Azure Active Directory Provider technical profile 'Get-RegisteredUserId' of policy 'B2C_1A_PasswordReset'. If it is a claim with
default value, add AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" to the output claim mapping.Output Claim 'password' is not supported in Azure Active Directory Provider
technical profile 'Get-RegisteredUserId' of policy 'B2C_1A_PasswordReset'. If it is a claim with default value, add AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" to the
output claim mapping.
InnerError:
RequestId: 3346b8e6-eaa7-4b51-9755-a08b2ce04860
DateTimeStamp: Tue, 14 Feb 2023 08:26:41 GMT
HttpStatusCode: BadRequest

This is my technical profile I use:

```
        <TechnicalProfile Id="Get-RegisteredUserId">
                <Metadata>
                    <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
                    <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
                    <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">An account could not be found for the provided user ID.</Item>
                </Metadata>
                <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
                <InputClaims>
                    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true" />
                </InputClaims>
                <OutputClaims>
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
        <!-- This is ok -->
                    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_RegisteredUserId" PartnerClaimType="extension_RegisteredUserId"/>
        <!-- This is not ok -->
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" PartnerClaimType="password"/>
                </OutputClaims>
                <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
            </TechnicalProfile>
```

which I call (in step 3 of the orchestration) prior to calling another technical profile that sends the extension_RegisteredUserId (and also should send the password) to an API (in step 4 of the orchestration). I can see the extension_RegisteredUserId getting sent across. Note also I do need to send the new password that they have chosen, if anyone has an idea of how to do this as well that would be great.

The user journey is this:

```
    <UserJourney Id="PasswordReset">
  <OrchestrationSteps>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="PasswordResetUsingEmailAddressExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="NewCredentials" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="GetRegisteredUserId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Get-RegisteredUserId" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="Web-API-ChangePassword" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="REST-API-ChangePassword" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
    <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
  </OrchestrationSteps>
  <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
</UserJourney>
```

The technical profile for the api call is this:

```
        <!-- Custom Restful service -->
    <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-API-ChangePassword">
      <DisplayName>Registers a User on the Profile API</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl">(url for api)</Item>
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
                    <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
        <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
      </Metadata>           
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="extension_RegisteredUserId" PartnerClaimType="registeredUserId"/>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" PartnerClaimType="oldPassword"/>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" PartnerClaimType="newPassword"/>
      </InputClaims>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
```

Any help would be very welcome. thank you

Comment: You cannot read the current password from Azure AD.
It is stored in non-reversible form so there is no way for Azure AD to give it to you.

Comment: I thought so. For security reasons, wouldn't make sense to be able to read it out. Had to ask though.

Comment: For more info, see this answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49215486/1342086

Comment: It's also helpful to know you can pass the password around, just within the scope of the orchestration step.